# most occuring show in mysql table

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following data set.

[image]

How would the query look if wanted the most occuring show on top and limit the result for 20 shows?

**EDIT**

I have searched on the web for this and i need to use the GROUP BY method from sql. but when i make the query

```
SELECT `show` FROM fans GROUP BY `show` LIMIT 20
```

i do not get the desired result.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: *cough* `count(*)` *cough*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.TotalCount
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  c.show, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    TableName c
            GROUP   BY c.show
        ) b ON a.show = b.show
ORDER   BY b.TotalCount DESC
LIMIT   20
```

if you want to list one record for every show, you can simply use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT  a.show, COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM    TableName a
GROUP   BY a.Show
ORDER   BY TotalCount DESC
LIMIT   20
```